# Unknown symbol in motor diagram

Tags: wiring, symbol

What is this marked symbol, please?

[image: wiring diagram]

Comment: you circled nine symbols

Comment: Looks to me like a series of a capacitor, a resistor or maybe fuse, and a connector.

Answer (score 6):

It's a three-phase magnetic circuit breaker.

- The parallel lines represent the contacts.
- The zig-zag represents the overload trip mechanism. It's the same symbol used for solenoid coils in, I think, an American symbol set.

Comment: I've always seen solenoid coils use the same bumpy inductor symbol as inductors and transformers.

Comment: I think it's a thermal overload device.

Comment: @Andyaka, I checked before I wrote it but couldn't find a standard to reference. Thermal is the one with two 3/4 circles touching. See https://www.design-point.com/wp-content/uploads/Collaborative-symbol-creation-768x451.png.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing.